Error saving correction: CloseEditor is not a function
We have a GUI that shows the data of SQL tables, there are some records that sometimes the values of some of their fields are not correct and we need to correct them by GUI, so the user can do it in this way easier.
Our intention is, that when the fields of one record are corrected, then all the fields of that record (including the new values of corrected fields), are saved in another table, not the source table.
The backend is with Java and the frontend is with Vue.js. When I run the backend and frontend and change the value of the fields by GUI, the logs in the backend show that the corrected value is passing to the backend but I get error for saving and the records don't save in the new table and of course, the window doesn't close after pressing the correction or cancel buttons, the error is:

Error saving correction
TypeError: closeEditor is not a function

while I defined it already.
I tried different ways to solve it but couldn't do it, that would be great if someone shared his/her knowledge in this field. here is the part of the code for saving the records:
<p-button icon="pi pi-save" label="Create Correction" severity="success"
                :disabled="!saveEnabled"
                @click="saveCorrectionAndClose"/>
      <p-button label="Cancel" @click="cancelAndClose"/>
setup() {
      let trade = ref(); // Store trade information
      const schema = ref({}); // Store the schema for editable fields
      const saveEnabled = ref(false); // Enable save button
      const tradeExport = ref();
      const tradeReconciliation = ref();
      const tradeValuation = ref();
      let closeEditor = null
  
      const confirm = useConfirm();
      const dialogRef = inject('dialogRef')
  
      const editableValues = ref([])

      function findByFileName(row,fieldName) {
        return row.fieldName === fieldName;
      }
const _loadTrade = () => {
        const newEditableValues = []
        const _displayedField = ref([]);
        if (trade.value.Asset_class === "CURR") {
          _displayedField.value = includedTradeField_CURR;
        } else {
          _displayedField.value = includedTradeField;
        }
        Object.keys(trade.value).forEach(function(key) {
            if (_displayedField.value.indexOf(key) > -1)
            {
                newEditableValues.push({
                    "fieldName": key,
                    "originalValue": trade.value[key] ? "" + trade.value[key] : "",
                    "value": trade.value[key] ? "" + trade.value[key] : "",
                    "changed": false,
                    "value2": ""
                })
            }
        });
        editableValues.value = newEditableValues;
const cancelAndClose = () => {
        if (editableValues.value && editableValues.value.find(it => it.changed)) {
          confirm.require({
            message: "Cancellation will discard any unsaved changes. Do you want to cancel?",
            header: "Unsaved changes",
            acceptLabel: "Yes",
            acceptClass: "p-button-secondary",
            rejectLabel: "No",
            accept: () => {
              closeEditor();
            }
          })
        } else {
          closeEditor();
        }
      }
      const saveCorrectionAndClose = () => {
      const correctionValues = {};
      let doSave = false;

      editableValues.value.forEach((eValue) => {
        if (eValue.changed) {
          correctionValues[eValue.fieldName] = eValue.value === "" ? null : eValue.value;
          doSave = true;
        }
      });

      if (doSave) {
        const tradeDetailsId = trade.value.TradeDetailsId; 
        // API call to save corrections
        client.post("/api/emir/trade/createCorrection/"+ trade.value.TradeDetailsId, correctionValues)
          .then(() => {
            console.log("Saving correction for tradeDetailsId: ", tradeDetailsId);
            console.log("Correction values: ", correctionValues);
            alert('Corrections saved successfully');
            closeEditor();
          })
          .catch(error => console.error('Error saving corrections', error));
          alert('Error saving corrections');
      } else {
        closeEditor();
      }
    };
return {
        editableValues,
        trade,tradeReconciliation,tradeExport,tradeValuation,
        onCellEditComplete,saveEnabled,
        formatXML,cancelChanges,
        // dataQualityInfo,
        // additionalInfo,
        saveCorrectionAndClose, cancelAndClose
      }

I tried  and (closeEditor as any)() but I got some other error and didn't work

in your setup function you have
let closeEditor = null
you need make sure that closeEditor is a function before you can execute it as closeEditor()
to test what am saying try
const closeEditor = () => {
    console.log(' I got called')
}

You should see " I got called" in the console
